# Multiply stringified units in Sass

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am passing values with units to a function and I want to multiply that unit value within that function. However I am finding that the value with units being passed is being interpolated as a string within the function itself, so is not letting me multiply it...

I have attempted the various strip-unit functions as proposed on the internet, however it seems that this runs into the same issue...

```
@function calcWidth($var1) {
  $res: $var1 * 10;

  @return $res;
}

...

.my-class {
  width: calcWidth(10px);
}
```

I usually end up with an error to the effect of:

```
SassError: Undefined operation: "10px times 10"
```

Adding a debug in: `@debug type-of($var1)` shows that my variable is a **string**.

I have, as I mentioned earlier that I attempted to use a strip-unit type function:

```
@function strip-unit($number) {
  @if type-of($number) == 'number' and not unitless($number) {
    @return $number / ($number * 0 + 1);
  }
  @return $number;
}
```

however this simply just returned the same thing...

How can I solve this?

Comment: Shouldn't you assign the value with `:`?  `$res: $var1 * 10;`

Comment: Indeed I should have, I was rushing my pseudocode

Comment: You shouldn't be getting errors. But did you also try switching the units in the variables? pass `width: calcWidth(10);` and multiply by a pixel unit `$res: $var1 * 10px;`

Comment: Seems to work fine in https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/0fbec9ccb721b94c6c2436f9d3582962?token=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&scope=gist,read:user